# Applying `=~` to a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
nameArray = ["Ashlee", "Sarah", "Aspen"]
symbolRegex = "=~".to_sym
```

I am doing:

```
nameArray.each do |name|
  name.send(symbolRegex, "/Aspen/")
end
```

I get this error:

```
type mismatch: String given
(repl):5:in `=~'
```

I was wondering how I could fix this.

Comment: There is no need to convert `"=~"` to a symbol. Just write `symbolRegex = :=~`. Ruby's convention is to use snake-case for names of variables and methods (`symbol_regex` rather than the camel-case `symbolRegex`).

Answer (score 3):

Pass a regex as the argument of `=~`. Either side of it has to be a regex; both cannot be a string:

```
name.send(symbolRegex, /Aspen/)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`=~` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) needs a [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html). Your code has `"/Aspen/"` which includes slashes so it *looks* like a Regexp but it is in fact a String. You should write `/Aspen/`.